# What is a robust & nifty way to cycle thru a string and shave off a part of it till

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I have a string and in some instances it can be over 150 chars in length(including space and special chars). I was just gonna take the curr length, minus 150 (if greater than 150) and with the remember, shave off a part of the string. I am curious if there is a robust way to do it? The issue is, I don't necessarily want to shave the end. I want to shave the part that resides in a "span" with a certain ID. I want to have that string section and append with "...". So, I have this.

For example. I have.

```
<div id="divid">
Funny thing is, I went to the store <span id="spanid">on a Tuesday afternoon while the sun was in the sky</span> and rode home with excitement and glee. Did I say it was Tuesday?
</div>
var txtcount = jQuery('#divid').text().length;
var spanidcount = jQuery('#spanid').text().length;
if(txtcount > 140){
    var tocut = txtcount - 140;
    // here I would reduce the contents of spanid so that the total string count is 140 or less. and have spanid end with "..." - with the ... counting toward the total of 140.
}
```

Comment: Do the html characters count towards the total goal of 150 (140?) or less characters in the string? (it's an additional 19 characters, plus the length of the id attribute itself...)

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is implement a truncate function. You don't have to extend the `String` prototype, but I did in this case. :P

http://jsfiddle.net/j89em/1/

```
String.prototype.truncate = function (len, trail) {
    len = len || 10; // default to 10
    trail = trail || '...';
    return len < this.length ? this.substring(0, len - trail.length) + trail : this;
};

var $div = $('div'),
    $span = $div.find('span');

$span.text($span.text().truncate(25));
```

So you could actually test the total test length and apply the truncate  method if needed.

```
if ($div.text().length > 140) {
   $span.text($span.text().truncate(25));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way would be to use CSS [text-overflow:ellipsis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow) on your div. Sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/JXsKw/1/).
The advantage of this way that you don't trust font size and variant letter width to not screw you up. You always cut the text exactly where you need it. And if `div` is resized, the ellipsis is automagically adjusted to the right length.

Comment: @eclanrs: Some people refer to it as the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Although it might well be that "150" characters is really a requirement (I don't see why it should, though).

Comment: @elclanrs The way I read the OP is that he wants to make the text fit. The rest is just his guess on how to proceed.

Comment: Oh, I see, XY problem seems to be the case.

Comment: This is wrong. He wants to cut the span text only if the div text length is greater than 140 characters.

Comment: Well, now that I notice, you're right, XY doesn't seem to be the problem then. Our solutions will work in any case.

Comment: @Trevor: Maybe OP is just wrong about how he could achieve his goal? This is definitely a good answer, because it's well possible that this is a clean solution for the underlying "X".

Comment: The question seems pretty straight forward. Total text > 140 char then reduce text in the middle.

Comment: @Trevor Yes, that is how he worded it. However character count is a useless metric in HTML context as it translates very poorly into actual width. There is no good reason to be trimming text based on it.

Comment: I should have been more clear - yes, the 140 is a requirement. The data comes back from the app and there might be instances in which it is greater than 140 chars. I slot one part of the data in the spanID, knowing that is the least neeed bit of info. So, I want to cut there.

Comment: @jamesemanon Ok, but do you mind explaining why character with is a requirement (as opposed to pixel width)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

**html:**

```
<p>Funny thing is, I went to the store <span>on a Tuesday afternoon while the sun was in the sky</span> and rode home with excitement and glee. Did I say it was Tuesday?</p>
<button>Reduce</button>
```

**jQ:**

```
var reduceStr = function(str, maxLen) {
    return str.substr(0, maxLen-1) + (str.length > maxLen ? '...' : '');
};

$('button').click(function(){
    $('span').text(reduceStr($('span').text(), 30));
});
```

Comment: Lol, similar but different. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Include this (plug-in) in a `script` tag or linked from an external .js file sometime after jQuery has been loaded:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.trimFluff = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            'childSelector': '#spanid',
            'maxLength': 140
        }, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            var container = $(this);
            var child = $(settings.childSelector);
            var containerLen = container.text().length;
            var childLen = child.text().length;
            var fluffToTrim = containerLen - settings.maxLength;
            if (containerLen > settings.maxLength) {
                if (fluffToTrim > childLen) { //'fluffToTrim' is larger than the child contents...
                    $(this).find(settings.childSelector).remove(); //remove child
                    containerLen = container.text().length; //recalc new length
                    fluffToTrim = containerLen - settings.maxLength; //recalc 'fluffToTrim'
                    if (containerLen > settings.maxLength) {
                        //remove "offending length" characters + 3 for the ellipsis and replace with the ellipsis
                        container.text(container.text().substring(0, containerLen - fluffToTrim + 3) + '...');
                        //string is now under (or equal to) 140 characters
                    }
                } else {
                    //remove "offending length" characters + 3 for the ellipsis, from the child, and replace with the ellipsis
                    child.text(child.text().substring(0, childLen - fluffToTrim + 3) + '...');
                }
            }
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Then call it like so:

```
$('#divid').trimFluff();
```

or pass in an options object. There are two options, `childSelector` which accepts any valid jQuery selector (or element, or jQuery object) and `maxLength` (which I hope is self-explanatory :) ).

Examples:

```
$('#divid').trimFluff({childSelector: 'span', maxLength: 150});
$('#divid').trimFluff({childSelector: $('#spanid'), maxLength: 140});
$('#divid').trimFluff({childSelector: 'span#spanid.customClass', maxLength: 160});

var s = document.getElementById('spanid');
$('divid').trimFluff({childSelector: s);
```

This will trim from the child first, keeping the left side, and if the text to to cut is larger than the child itself, it will remove the child entirely and trim the remaining contents of the `div` (or other container) until the text is less than the `maxLength`.

This does not do virtually any error checking, but it will work with any jQuery object where the `text()` function does something.

Have fun with it.